# Looking for a story where humans fight aliens with waves of soldiers

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Story about how an alien race kinda helps humans expand but then war breaks out with the central races and humans beat the biggest army by sending wave on waves of soldiers. The original race is surprised and confused that the humans keep sharing everything with them. Best I can remember but would love to find it.

Also looking for aliens go on a safari but they pick Australia and get messed up by the local animals

Comment: Was this a novel? A short story? Magazine article? Please visit https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and see if you can elicit more details. And I may know the second story, but you need to split it off into a second question.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/HFY/comments/606r1y/textearth_fuck_yeah_found_on_tumblr/

Comment: 1 Short story - And 2 100% what I was looking for on the second story thank you so much!

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/xt2nX4s.png

Comment: Found in on imgur humanity f@ck yeah

Comment: You can post that as an answer, and accept it tomorrow, 48 hours after asking, by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.